# How to set SharePoint "Author" in silverlight client object model?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a Silverlight web part for SharePoint 2010. I want to set the "Author" of `ListItem` in my code. So I am using the following code

```
  internal void Save()
        {

            ClientContext context = ClientContext.Current            

            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Time Log");

            ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
            listItem["Client"] = Client.Id;
            listItem["EventDate"] = StartDateTime;
            listItem["EndDate"] = EndDateTime;
            listItem["Service"] = ClientService;
            listItem["Description"] = Description;

            listItem["Author"] = "shailesh";
            listItem["Editor"] = "shailesh";

            listItem.Update();

            context.ExecuteQueryAsync(Success, Fail);

        }
```

When I use this code it goes into the method "Fail" because of line `listItem["Author"] = "shailesh";`. I have read that we can do it in managed client object model using credential property of `ClientContext`. But it looks like that there is no way of setting "Author" in Silverlight client object model. Can you please tell any other way from which we can set the "Author" ?

If there is any way please suggest it and if possible please provide some code or give some useful link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert user ID instead of login name.
For example:

```
 listItem["Author"] = 8;
 listItem["Editor"] = 11;
```