# How to impersonate using silverlight client object model?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint-2010, impersonation, sharepoint-clientobject

I am developing silverlight web part for sharepoint 2010 in C#.In silverlight client object model the sharepoint 2010 takes the current user credential by using the following statement

```
 ClientContext clientContext = ClientContext.Current;
```

Now I want to login programatically with different user name and password. So that it can access only that particular user data. But I found that there is no clientContext.Credentials in silverlight client object. We can insert the data for another user by using the following link

[How to set SharePoint "Author" in silverlight client object model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606163/how-to-set-sharepoint-author-in-silverlight-client-object-model)

But I am not aware how we can get the data for that particular user by passing the credentails. How can I login with different user name and password programatically so that I can access that particular user data ? If there is any way to do that please tell me. Can we do it through web services ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Client Object Model is a subset of Server Object Model and one of the limitations of Client Object model is that it doesn't support impersonation.

One workaround will be to call a WCF endpoint via jQuery by passing all the data.
Then WCF can impersonate the call to SharePoint by processing the data on some else's behalf